# ¿Cómo crear un proyecto ionic con la versión 6 especificamente?

Tags: nodejs, ionic, npm

Tuve un problema con mi anterior proyecto, así que intento crear otro, primero instalando ionic 6

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@6
```

Esto me instala la versión `6.20.9`

Pero al crear el proyecto con

```
ionic start proyecto
```

El proyecto me viene con la versión 7 de ionic, antes lo tenía con la versión 6.1.9.

Debo aclarar que lo estoy trabajando con Angular, estás son mis versiones.

```
NPM: 14.15.5

Typescript: 4.3.5

Angular: 12.2.17
```